# Extracting values from a map image (jpg)

Tags: python, image-segmentation, opencv

Not sure if this is the right platform but I'm in a bit of a fix here.
I'm trying to convert this image(jpg) to a raster wherein, the colormap attached shows the values. I'm aware I need to use openCV and segmentation for it but since the actual data is in only very few pixels (the rest of the image is just a basemap), I don't know how to go about it.

If anyone can help with it, I'll be really grateful. Thank you! [image: radar Doppler image]